# Styling/Formatting an Android String resource

Tags: java, android, resources, format

Im trying to fill an activity with a huge string. 
I formatted so there are new lines and bold font. Now i want the title to have a bigger font size and "\t"  also doesnt work. 
Do you have ans ideas how to do a tabulator and font resizing? 
I dont want to change anything inside my activity to keep it as generic as possible. I need it for 15 different things...
I just load the string into a textview inside a scrollview. I may use  a fragment for the title but i would more like to resize the font. And i dont have any idea for the tabulator.

Comment: please, share your current source code which refers to your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do this:

Use html format. Put your string with html format e.g: `<p>test&#09;1<p>`.

`&#09;` is ASCII code for `\t`.

If you put your string on string.xml, put like this:

`<string name="test"><![CDATA[<p>test&#09;1<p>]]></string>`

and on Java, get the string by calling `Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.test))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Html.fromHtml("\t")` for the tabulator. And resizing the text, just use textSize attribute in XML file with a value of your needs.